# Use Ruby library with PHP and/or VB.net

Tags: php, ruby, vb.net

I have a Ruby library that uses a REST API but I want to use the library and all other Ruby scripts on a website, or even in vb.net.

Are there any ways to use Ruby in combination with PHP without Rails? And can I implement Ruby in vb.net?

I'm not asking how to translate Ruby to vb.net. I know how that goes and how hard it is, so my questions are:

1. Can Ruby be used as a backend language without using Ruby on Rails?
2. Is there any way to implement Ruby into vb.net ?

Comment: i realize that you might think its a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266044/using-ruby-library-in-php-application) but i reviewed all the answers and none of them have my answers

Comment: are you able to call the ruby functions you need as command line scripts?

Comment: Rails is only one way that Ruby is used for web-services. Without much more detail about your experience and system we can only give broad answers, which does you no good. I suggest doing more research about how to write web services in Ruby and see how those fit your scenario. Without more information we'd have to write a tutorial starting with basic HTTP and CGI and move forward, which would be off-topic too.

Comment: i am expert in php, and new to ruby, i was looking for ways to learn rails and i found this [rails for zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) would you recommend it ? @theTinMan

Answer (score -2):

Effectively you are trying to run PHP in a scripting shell.  I found two links that might help you:
[PHP as a scripting language in C#](http://www.php-compiler.net/blog/2011/php-code-c-sharp)
[.Net Scripting Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997911/net-scripting-languages)

Hopefully you can get what you need from there.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what your problem is - answering with links is considered useful, particularly as copying and pasting the information from the linked articles are plagiarism.  You are also providing negative feedback which will discourage people from anwering. Better formed sentences would help as well.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought that it was clear. One of the reason for flagging an answer as low quality (what I did with yours) or to downvote it (what I didn't do) is precisely consisting in links. The fact that an answer is mostly formed by links has been off-topic in SO since always (at least, since I am a member). You are free to do whatever you want (-> my second time saying this today!? what I also thought that was evident); it was just an advice (don't worry; last one to you). Apologies about my not-too-clear first comment, but as said I thought that this point was evident to everyone.

Comment: @Arkitec, while you might not like the policy, link-only answers are discouraged. Links rot and break and without some additional text an answer mostly consisting of the link will make no sense and provide nothing for future searchers . Summarizing the content and explaining why it will help is the way to provide the information, and the link and giving credit to the original author avoids plagiarism.  Please read [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as “not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: I'd recommend searching on [meta] to get a good idea of the community's feelings about [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=link-only+answers). You are welcome to start a discussion on [meta] about the subject if you'd like.

Comment: Okay, thanks to the both of you for the feedback - I will try to improve the quality of my answers by explaining/summarizing why a link might be useful.  Tin Man, I will check out the references mentioned ot understand a bit more.